# sql server 2014 bulk insert with utf-8 characters

Tags: sql-server, csv, utf-8

I need to import some data from some small csv files containing cyrillic and other utf-8 Characters in SQL Server 2014.

I know that only sqlserver 2016 (13) supports utf-8 natively but....

Googleing around I built this procedure:

```
BULK INSERT [test].[dbo].[csv]
FROM 'C:\Book1.csv'
WITH
(
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
 ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
 ,DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'
 ,CODEPAGE       = 'OEM'
 ,FIRSTROW       = 1
 ,TABLOCK
)
```

that works well

But, since files to import have different structures (different field names in different position), I thought best solution would be to use a .fmt file for each file structure, therefore something like this:

```
BULK INSERT [test].[dbo].[csv]
FROM 'C:\Book1.csv'
WITH
(
  FORMATFILE = 'C:\csv.FMT'
 ,DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'
 ,CODEPAGE       = 'OEM'
 ,FIRSTROW       = 1
 ,TABLOCK
)
```

WHERE

> csv.fmt is

```
12.0
9
1  SQLNCHAR     2       200     ","     1     UserID                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
2  SQLNCHAR     2       60      ","     2     TypeID                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
3  SQLNCHAR     2       60      ","     3     TrackingID             Latin1_General_CI_AS
4  SQLNCHAR     2       200     ","     4     Name                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
5  SQLNCHAR     2       200     ","     5     Address                Latin1_General_CI_AS
6  SQLNCHAR     2       20      ","     6     PostalCode             Latin1_General_CI_AS
7  SQLNCHAR     2       200     ","     7     City                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
8  SQLNCHAR     2       200     ","     8     StateOrProvince         Latin1_General_CI_AS
9  SQLNCHAR     2       20      "\n"    9     CountryID              Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

but I get

> The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I tried with different versions of terminator: "\n", "\r\n", also "\r\0\n\0" as suggested by
`bcp test.dbo.csv format nul -F 1 -w -T -f csv.fmt`

but none works.
Can suggest direction?
Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that you specify the codepage as OEM, which is an 8-bit encoding (each character uses one byte). So, the CSV parser thinks it can simply count bytes to determine the column offsets. However, the file uses UTF-8, where some (actually, most) characters need more than 1 byte (eg. `"Ж"` is encoded with 2 bytes). Therefore the columns are wider (in terms of bytes) than the number of characters you specify.

Comment: Well, I tried also with ACP, 866, 1252 but got same result
not tested 65001 since utf-8 is not supported

Comment: These are 8-bit encodings as well, as far as I can tell. Can you convert the input file to an encoding that is supported, maybe UTF-16/UCS-2?

Comment: Yes, sure, tried to converted csv file to UCS-2 BE BOM, but this is the result:
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 2 (TypeID).
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
Seems it does not recognize the field and the row terminators:
Just to be more clear if set field and row terminator rispectively to "," and "\n" it works, if I use the FORMATFILE with same settings.. returns the above error